# Environment variables in Angular app built using .NET Core JavaScriptServices

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I see that like most SPA frameworks, Angular provides an easy way to pass environment specific configuration to the app. I am using a Angular app scaffolded by the .NET Core 2.0 project. I have tried using both the Angular CLI environments files and the webpack DefinePlugin to provide environment variables to my app. What am I missing?

This is what I'd like:

```
import { environment } from './environment';

export class MyComponent {
    constructor() {
        // Logs localhost:5001 in dev and www.myapi.com in prod
        console.log(process.env.API_URL);
    }
}
```

But using the .NET Core JavaScriptServices. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, could you enlighten us?

Comment: My solution was not ideal. I had to use global JavaScript variables. I tried it using webpack using the define plugin but then changed to just writing the variable to the layout on the server with .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the environments is that you have a `environment.{ENV}.ts` for each environment you may use, then in your `.angular-cli.json` you define the name of them:

```
...
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
...
```

You have to set this environment files manually:

In your environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL: 'http://localhost:5001'
}
```

In your environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API_URL: 'http://www.myapi.com'
}
```

Then when you want to you some of this environment properties you may import the environment object to your .ts file and call it.

This `process.env` that you're calling is referring to node's environment.

Comment: How would you use the Angular CLI with .NET Core JavaScriptServices?

Comment: Have no idea. I use angular-cli alone.

Comment: Angular's notion of 'environment' is completely misnamed. These are really 'configurations' (ie: debug VS release), which in every other ecosystem (iOS/Android/.NET) you can run any number of environments in any configuration (debug or release). Since Angular conflates these two concepts, you are left having to hack workarounds to support environments without any out-of-box support for anything beyond 'configurations'  :(

Here is one way: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#pass-data-from-net-code-into-typescript-code